# Sharedpreferences - crashes on startup

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to write an activity that would be able to both write and read sharedpreferences data.

I initiate SharedPreferences at the beginning

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Then this function writes an int to SP and call another function.

```
public void SetHue(int i)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("storedInt", i); // value to store
    editor.commit();
    ApplyHue();
}
```

this other function should read that int from SP...

```
    public void ApplyHue()
    {   
    int hueInt = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
    /// adjust background image hue according to hueInt.
    }
```

I can't simply pass this int from one function to another, because I need other activities to be able to run ApplyHue() function, which should use hueInt from memory.

What do you think might be causing it to crash?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the logcat/stacktrace of the crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you wrote this line in the class before your onCreate method.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Decalare `SharedPreferences preferences;` in the class and then in onCreate

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Hopefully your problem will be solved

Comment: yeah,context is not attached yet, so you can't get SP when declares preferences field